# find optimum values of model iteratively

Tags: matlab

Given that I have a model that can be expressed as:

```
y = a + b*st + c*d2
```

where st is a smoothed version of some data, and a, b and c are model coffieicients that are unknown. An iterative process should be used to find the best values for a, b, and c and also an additional value alpha, shown below.

Here, I show an example using some data that I have. I'll only show a small fraction of the data here to get an idea of what I have:

```
17.1003710350253    16.7250000000000    681.521316544969
17.0325989276234    18.0540000000000    676.656460644882
17.0113862864815    16.2460000000000    671.738125420192
16.8744356336601    15.1580000000000    666.767363772145
16.5537077980594    12.8830000000000    661.739644621949
16.0646524243248    10.4710000000000    656.656219934146
15.5904357723302    9.35000000000000    651.523986525985
15.2894427136087    12.4580000000000    646.344231349275
15.1181450512182    9.68700000000000    641.118300709434
15.0074128442766    10.4080000000000    635.847600747838
14.9330905954828    11.5330000000000    630.533597865332
14.8201069920058    10.6830000000000    625.177819082427
16.3126863409751    15.9610000000000    619.781852331734
16.2700386755872    16.3580000000000    614.347346678083
15.8072873786912    10.8300000000000    608.876012461843
15.3788908036751    7.55000000000000    603.369621360944
15.0694302370038    13.1960000000000    597.830006367160
14.6313314652840    8.36200000000000    592.259061672302
14.2479738025295    9.03000000000000    586.658742460043
13.8147156115234    5.29100000000000    581.031064599264
13.5384821473624    7.22100000000000    575.378104234926
13.3603543306796    8.22900000000000    569.701997272687
13.2469020140965    9.07300000000000    564.004938753678
13.2064193251406    12.0920000000000    558.289182116093
13.1513460035983    12.2040000000000    552.557038340513
12.8747853506079    4.46200000000000    546.810874976187
12.5948999131388    4.61200000000000    541.053115045791
12.3969691298003    6.83300000000000    535.286235826545
12.1145822760120    2.43800000000000    529.512767505944
11.9541188991626    2.46700000000000    523.735291710730
11.7457790927936    4.15000000000000    517.956439908176
11.5202981254529    4.47000000000000    512.178891679167
11.2824263926694    2.62100000000000    506.405372863054
11.0981930749608    2.50000000000000    500.638653574697
10.8686514170776    1.66300000000000    494.881546094641
10.7122053911554    1.68800000000000    489.136902633882
10.6255883267131    2.48800000000000    483.407612975178
10.4979083986908    4.65800000000000    477.696601993434
10.3598092538338    4.81700000000000    472.006827058220
10.1929490084608    2.46700000000000    466.341275322034
10.1367069580204    2.36700000000000    460.702960898512
10.0194072271384    4.87800000000000    455.094921935306
9.88627023967911    3.53700000000000    449.520217586971
9.69091601129389    0.417000000000000   443.981924893704
9.48684595125235    -0.567000000000000  438.483135572389
9.30742664359900    0.892000000000000   433.026952726910
9.18283037670750    1.50000000000000    427.616487485241
9.02385722622626    1.75800000000000    422.254855571341
8.90355705229410    2.46700000000000    416.945173820367
8.76138912769045    1.99200000000000    411.690556646207
8.61299614111510    0.463000000000000   406.494112470755
8.56293606861698    6.55000000000000    401.358940124780
8.47831879772002    4.65000000000000    396.288125230599
8.42736865902327    6.45000000000000    391.284736577104
8.26325535934842    -1.37900000000000   386.351822497948
8.14547793724500    1.37900000000000    381.492407263967
8.00075641792910    -1.03700000000000   376.709487501030
7.83932517791044    -1.66700000000000   372.006028644665
7.68389447250257    -4.12900000000000   367.384961442799
7.63402151555169    -2.57900000000000   362.849178517935
```

The results that follow probably won't be meaningful as the full data would be needed (but this is an example). Using this data I have tried to solve iteratively by

```
    y = d(:,1);
    d1 = d(:,2);
    d2 = d(:,3);

    alpha_o = linspace(0.01,1,10);
    a = linspace(0.01,1,10);
    b = linspace(0.01,1,10);
    c = linspace(0.01,1,10);
```

defining different values for a, b, and c as well as another term alpha, which is used in the model, and am now going to find every possible combination of these parameters and see which combination provides the best fit to the data:

```
% every possible combination of values
xx = combvec(alpha_o,a,b,c);

% loop through each possible combination of values
for j = 1:size(xx,2);
    alpha_o = xx(1,j);
    a_o = xx(2,j);
    b_o = xx(3,j);
    c_o = xx(4,j);

    st = d1(1);
    for i = 2:length(d1);
        st(i) = alpha_o.*d1(i) + (1-alpha_o).*st(i-1);
    end
    st = st(:);

    y_pred = a_o + (b_o*st) + (c_o*d2);
    mae(j) = nanmean(abs(y - y_pred));
end
```

I can then re-run the model using these optimum values:

```
[id1,id2] = min(mae);
alpha_opt = xx(:,id2);
st = d1(1);
for i = 2:length(d1);
    st(i) = alpha_opt(1).*d1(i) + (1-alpha_opt(1)).*st(i-1);
end
st = st(:);

y_pred = alpha_opt(2) + (alpha_opt(3)*st) + (alpha_opt(4)*d2);
mae_final = nanmean(abs(y - y_pred));
```

However, to reach a final answer I would need to increase the number of initial guesses to more than 10 for each variable. This will take a long time to run. Thereofre, I am wondering if there is a better method for what I am trying to do here? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Advice: don't go iterative, go Least-Squares, see [`lscov`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lscov.html). Probably faster and better than iterating

Comment: But that won't let me restrict the ranges of the values that are selected. I think I need to do this in order to allow the values to be meaningful.

Comment: What do you mean by *restrict the ranges of the values that are selected*? `lscov` is just the regular least-squares method of finding a best fitting equation using all points. If you do not which all points to be included, use things like outlier detection first.

Comment: For example, one of the paramerters, alpha, is used in the section of the code which applies an exponential filter, therefore it has to be between 0 and 1. I think that the approach that you suggest would find the best value, which in this case might not be accurate. Please provide an example, if possible.

Comment: You can still use least-squares on the `y = a + b*st + c*d2` part. In addition you could use your brutal force strategy or another non-linear optimizer for calculating alpha. This secondary optimization would do the least square calculation every loop, but least-squares is very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some thoughts: If you could decrease the amount of computation within each for loop, you could possibly speed it up. One possible way is to look for common factors between each loop and move it outside for loop:

If you look at the iteration, you'll see

> st(1) = d1(1)
>
> st(2) = *a* * d1(2) + (1-*a*) * st(1) =  *a* *d1(2) + (1-*a*)*d1(1)
>
> st(3) = *a* * d1(3) + (1-*a*) * st(2) = *a* * d1(3) + *a* *(1-*a*)*d1(2) +(1-*a*)^2 * d1(1)
>
> st(n) = *a* * d1(n) + *a* *(1-*a*)*d1(n-1) + *a* *(1-*a*)^2 * d1(n-2) + ... +(1-*a*)^(n-1)*d1(1)

Which means `st` can be calculated by multiplying these two matrices (here I use n=4 for example to illustrate the concept) and sum along the first dimension:

```
temp1 = [  0      0       0          a     ;
           0      0       a       a(1-a)   ;
           0      a     a(1-a)    a(1-a)^2 ;
           1     (1-a)   (1-a)^2   (1-a)^3 ;]

temp2 = [  0      0        0       d1(4) ;
           0      0      d1(3)     d1(3) ;
           0     d1(2)   d1(2)     d1(2) ;
          d1(1)  d1(1)   d1(1)     d1(1) ;]

st = sum(temp1.*temp2,1)
```

Here's codes that utilize this concept: Computation has been moved out of the inner for loop and only assignment is left.

```
 alpha_o = linspace(0.01,1,10);
 xx = nchoosek(alpha_o, 4);
 n = size(d1,1);
 matrix_d1 = zeros(n, n);
 d2 = d2';  % To make the dimension of d2 and st the same.

 for ii = 1:n 
     matrix_d1(n-ii+1:n, ii) = d1(1:ii);
 end

 st = zeros(size(d1)');  % Pre-allocation of matrix will improve speed. 
 mae = zeros(1,size(xx,1));
 matrix_alpha = zeros(n, n);

 for j = 1 : size(xx,1)
    alpha_o = xx(j,1);
    temp = (power(1-alpha_o, [0:n-1])*alpha_o)';
    matrix_alpha(n,:) = power(1-alpha_o, [0:n-1]);
    for ii = 2:n
        matrix_alpha(n-ii+1:n-1, ii) = temp(1:ii-1);
    end
    st = sum(matrix_d1.*matrix_alpha, 1);
    y_pred = xx(j,2) + xx(j,3)*st + xx(j,4)*d2;
    mae(j) = nanmean(abs(y - y_pred));
end
```

Then :

```
idx = find(min(mae));
alpha_opt = xx(idx,:);
st = zeros(size(d1)');
temp = (power(1-alpha_opt(1), [0:n-1])*alpha_opt(1))';
matrix_alpha = zeros(n, n);
matrix_alpha(n,:) = power(1-alpha_opt(1), [0:n-1]);;
for ii = 2:n
    matrix_alpha(n-ii+1:n-1, ii) = temp(1:ii-1);
end
st = sum(matrix_d1.*matrix_alpha, 1);   
y_pred = alpha_opt(2) + (alpha_opt(3)*st) + (alpha_opt(4)*d2);
mae_final = nanmean(abs(y - y_pred));
```

Let me know if this helps !

Comment: Is that vectorization correct? The original has an iterative term `st(i-1)` appearing.

Comment: @JJM Driessen Thanks for pointing that out to me!  I've updated my answer.